# Controlling unpredictable (to me) y-axis behavior using gap.barplot()

Tags: r, plot

I have a barplot with y-axis break for 10 pairs of data points (matrix A). I want the exact same barplot except a subset of just five of these pairs (matrix B). But when I plot B, the y-axis seems to begin not at 0, but at the minimum y value in the data.

I've tried specifying ylim=c(0,300), but it does not behave as expected with the axis break. Anyone have advice on having the same y-axis ranges for plots A and B?

```
A <- rbind( NA, 
        c(7.31,8.13,0.44,60.50,8.51,19.25,10.50,25.86,296.64,44.86), 
        c(6.65,6.08,0.34,58.88,8.08,24.83,9.05,47.89,240.31,36.31))
B <- A[,c(4,6,8,9,10)]

pA <- gap.barplot(A, 
            gap=c(65,230), 
            ytics=c(0,25,50,250,275,300),
            xaxt='n')

pB <- gap.barplot(B, 
            gap=c(65,230), 
            ytics=c(0,25,50,250,275,300),
            xaxt='n')
```

**Graph of pA**

[image: pA]

**Graph of pB**

[image: pB]

(The NA values are in there for spacing, by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with specifying the y-limits.

```
#loading package
library(plotrix)

pB <- gap.barplot(B, 
              gap=c(65,230), 
              ytics=c(0,25,50,250,275,300),
              xaxt='n',
              ylim=c(0,135))
```

[I can't embed pictures in my posts yet, so here's a link to the plot made by this code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nt8V.jpg)

[This reference page for the gap.barplot function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/gap.barplot/) says that

> If the user does not ask for specific y limits, the function will calculate limits based on the range of the data values. If passing specific limits, remember to subtract the gap from the upper limit.

Since the barplot's gap is from 65 to 230, subtract 165 (that's 230 - 65) from the upper limit to get the real upper limit, 135. Another way to look at it is that the you want your plot to be 135 units tall (0 to 65, then 230 to 300), the y-limits will be `ylim=c(0,135)`.

Just add `ylim=c(0,135)` to what you already have for plot B, and you're good.

Comment: Missed that note in the documentation. Thanks!